# Print new line before the logging line, with a logging framework in Java

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

With `Slf4j`, is it possible to print a new line before the logger line, with a single line of code.

**Original code:**

```
System.out.println();
logger.info("tmp file deleted, file path: {}", tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to merge the first line into the second line in above code, while still get the same output?
  I know it's easy to add a new line after the log line with `\n`, but what about before the log line, without the additional first line.
- If such a feature doesn't exists yet, then do you think it could be easily implemented, and wouldn't it be useful, at least in some case?
  e.g a method like this:

  `Logger.info(int prefixNewLineCount, String format, Object... arguments)`

  Where the first param specify count of prefix emtpy lines.

Comment: Is this what you want? just add a \n before you log. logger.info("*\n* tmp file deleted, file path: {}", tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: @SaifAhmad No, because that will break the original output into 2 lines, what I want is an empty line, followed by a line contains the whole logging line.

Comment: Maybe change the log format in the configuration file so that it starts with a "\\n"?

Comment: Log output consists normally of some kind of message and a format. Set the format to show only the message and log an empty message and set the format back.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen For this case, I was trying to make the output of test case shown in groups separated by emtpy lines, so that easier to read. But, I think there could be more application of this feature which I could not thought of for now.

Comment: String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
logger.info("{}tmp file deleted, file path: {}", lineSeparator , tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Well I believe this shouldn't come under the realm of logging, its more like formatting or decorating. But this is primarily an opinion. If you really want it, why not create a wrapper over Logger and use your wrapper class instead for logging.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj It could be easily implemented with an util class, but not very maintainable for long term, so I am looking for a solution that the community accepts & maintains, if any. If there isn't then I'd prefer with the additional line `System.out.println()` before the logging line as shown in the question itself.

Comment: @EricWang don’t Think about  this like that. Tests should all pass. If not, use your ide’s test runner support to get a good and efficient overview.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yeah, you are right, the test do passed, but still I want to check the output sometimes.

Comment: @EricWang After a while I think you will find that you are only interested in knowing if anything fails (and then it is the job of the test framework to print out the necessary information to debug the issue if you have written the tests properly).   Don't pollute your logs and standard output.

Answer (score 1):

This actually depends on the logging implementation of SLF4j you are using with (logback,Log4j,JUL ect).
For this kind of requirement I did something like below using MDC (mapped diagnostic context). If This would help.

```
public class Test
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( "TEST" );

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        MDC.put( "newLine", "\n" );

        //your logic here

        LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "log message one " );
        LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "log message tow" );
        LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "log message three" );
        LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "log message four" );
    }

}
```

then in the log42 configuration file use `%X{newLine}` to append `'\n'` for each log message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="10">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%X{newLine} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="test" fileName=".\src\test\resources\test.log" />
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="TEST" level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="test"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

out put

```
 12:10:36.412 [main] INFO  tbx.TEST - log message one 

 12:10:36.418 [main] INFO  tbx.TEST - log message tow

 12:10:36.418 [main] INFO  tbx.TEST - log message three

 12:10:36.418 [main] INFO  tbx.TEST - log message four
```